# onbeforeunload function created in Vaadin 7 returning empty string still displays prompt in IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vaadin, onbeforeunload

I'm not sure if this is a Javascript problem, or a Vaadin problem, so I figured it was best to ask here than on the Vaadin forums.

In order to clean up resources immediately when the browser is closed (when possible), I have added the following code to my Vaadin application:

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().addFunction("catchClose", new JavaScriptFunction() {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Override
public void call(JSONArray arguments) throws JSONException {
    VaadinSession.getCurrent().close();
    /*causes detach() to be called which does all my cleanup*/
}
});

Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute(
    "window.addEventListener('beforeunload', "
                + "function() {"
                + "var e = window.event;"
                + "e.returnValue = '';"
                + "catchClose(); "
                + "return '';"
            + "}, false);"
    );
```

I have also tried setting the onbeforeunload function directly, rather than adding an event listener, as mentioned in [this post](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/2518250/2711211) on the Vaadin forums.

In Firefox this works as expected, the event is sent back up to the server *with no prompt being displayed asking the user if they want to leave the page*. It just let's them leave.

However, in IE 10 (and Chrome, but only IE 10 is relevant right now) the message is still sent, which closes my Vaadin Session but asks the user to confirm if they want to leave or not. Since I have already closed the session, this will obviously cause some big issues if they choose to stay.

According to [the IE documentation on the onbeforeunload event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the dialog should not pop up if I am returning an empty value. In addition to returning an empty string, I have also tried returning `null` and `false`, which have each set the message of the prompt to be "null" and "false". I have also tried without setting the `e.returnValue` at all, and setting the `e.returnValue` to `null` or `false`, and various permutations of the above attempts combined.

So in short, the question is how do I need to change the above code to prevent the "Are you sure you want to leave" prompt from displaying in IE 10? Is there something wrong with the Javascript, or something I missed in the IE documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Returning an empty value I'm guessing is an unclear way of saying return undefined... your function should either just say `return;` with no value, `return undefined;`, or `return expression;`, where expression evaluates to undefined (e.g. `window.vrenifbruwfgw`, `void(0)`, etc...)